# System will not power down on shutdown

Tags: shutdown, suspend, restart

I'm having problems with shutdown on my Dell Inspiron 14z-5423. When I shut down, I hear the hard disk stop but the machine does not actually power down. Interestingly, when I do a restart, the machine powers off just fine and then powers on a few seconds later as expected. Relative linux newbie here - what logs would be good to look at?

I have tried following command but it doesn't make any difference:

```
    sudo shutdown -P now
```

Comment: Did you append `sudo`? Actually before editing your post, you didn't mention it.. I assumed that you used sudo..

Comment: If the hard disk stops, what is left on? If the fan still running or is the screen black but on?

Comment: Saurav, thanks for editing - I was using sudo. minerz, the fan is still running, the display is either showing the "ubuntu dots" shutdown screen or when I get the messages displayed it stops on [timestamp] Powering down (Can't remember the exact message, sorry).

Answer (score 0):

You may want to halt the system after shutdown. Try the following command.

```
sudo shutdown -H now
```